# debezium Postgres bit varying field

Tags: postgresql, field, bit, decoding, debezium

I'm having trouble converting data coming out of debezium (postgres) on a bit varying(36) column.   Example inputs and outputs are provided below.

Documentation says (under "basic types" section):

**PostgreSQL data type**    **Literal type (schema type)**

BIT( > 1)                         BYTES

**Semantic type (schema name) and Notes
**
io.debezium.data.Bits

The length schema parameter contains an integer that represents the number of bits. The resulting byte[] contains the bits in little-endian form and is sized to contain the specified number of bits. For example, numBytes = n/8 + (n % 8 == 0 ? 0 : 1) where n is the number of bits.

I'm not sure how to interpret the notes.  I've tried  a few things but I'm striking out.

A couple example inputs/outputs:

My input value       Debezium Output value
B'100001'            IQ==
B'100001111000'      eAg=

My connector config is simple and was created as follows (not sure if this matters):
{
"name": "pg-orders-source",
"config": {
"connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector",
"database.hostname": "postgres",
"database.port": "5432",
"database.user": "postgres",
"database.password": "postgres",
"database.dbname": "postgres",
"database.server.name": "myserver",
"errors.log.enable": "true",
"plugin.name": "wal2json",
"table.include.list": "public.customers"
}
}

I tried converting IQ== to ascii binary and then endian conversion.  Can't determine where length of data and actual value are encoded.

Any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: Does [What is Endianness?](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/what-is-endianness-big-endian-vs-little-endian/) help?

Comment: I printed out the native endianness in my java app and it's little endian.  So now I'm more confused.   In the one example in the original question, IQ== represents the number of bits (which is 36 for the postgres column, or 6 for the data) and the bits '100001'.   Head scratcher...